# Github Merge pull request somehow re-wrote history

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch, git-history-graph

At my workplace we commit code by first creating a branch, creating a pull request in our Github repo for that branch, and then someone reviews it and hits "Merge pull request". It's a pretty standard workflow.

Normally when we hit "Merge pull request" Github creates a new commit called "Merge pull request #1234 from branchname" with 2 parents - The HEAD of master, and the latest commit in the PR.

Today I merged a PR as normal and somehow Github decided instead of using the HEAD of master as one of the parents it would use a commit from over a day ago (we do 20 - 30 commits a day). This commit it used was the commit the PR branch was based off. This has caused the master branch to lose all commits from between then and this PR merge.

Does anyone know how this could have happened? Is this a bug with Github? Or did the developer who submitted the PR do something bad that could have overwritten master? I thought all commits would simply be merged into master without any rebasing or history re-writing in Github.

Comment: i don't think that a developer can do anything bad in this regard; you either hit a bug with github or the assumption that there had been commits already pushed to github does not hold (i'd suspect the latter).

Comment: Is it public, can you link to the relevant commit?

Comment: Did you attempt to merge remotely from the command line, or use GitHub's green "Merge" button?

Comment: It's a private repository unfortunately otherwise I would link it. I merged using Githubs green merge button, we always merge this way.

Comment: Github has all the commits that have gone missing from master, they're still in our deploy-staging and deploy-prod branches (master is merged into these after it has been tested)

Comment: Without warning too? :O I'd report to GitHub if you strongly feel it is an error on GitHub's part. support@github.com

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Github and it turns out someone had force pushed to master by accident because the latest versions of git appear to both force push master and your branch when force pushing. We also didn't have Githubs protected branches (https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks) enabled though we do now to prevent this in the future.